# How to use single controller for multiple views in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am working with codeigniter 4,I have two different "form"(two different files in view) Right now i am trying to save "second form data" (first form data already submitted successfully) into database (table name is "additional_info" with columns/fields (id,user_id,address,gender),How can i do this ? In short i want to know following things

1. Suppose i am working on admin panel and i have to save multiple form data so should i create different multiple controller or model for this ?
2. if no then how can we manage multiple form with single controller and single model

Here is my current code in "routes.php"

```php
$routes->post('addnewuser', 'STD::adduser2');
```

Here is my controller code

```php
    public function adduser2()
    {
        $userModel = new UserModel();
        $result = [
            'name' => $this->request->getVar('name'),
            'gen' => $this->request->getVar('gen'),
            'dob' => $this->request->getVar('dob'),
            'email'  => $this->request->getVar('email'),
            'pwd'  => md5($this->request->getVar('pwd')),
        ];
          
        $save=$userModel->insert($result);
     }
```

Here is my model file code

```php
namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;
class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table2 = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey2 = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields2 = ['email', 'password']; // first table 
    

    protected $table2 = 'additional_info';
    protected $primaryKey2 = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields2 = ['user_id', 'address', 'gender']; // second table (trying to insert data)
}
```

Comment: "_Should I [...]_" generally lends itself to appealing for subjective, opinion-based answers.  Stack Overflow tries to avoid such questions.

Comment: You can have a single POST endpoint that handles multiple form. Or you can have multiple different POST endpoints to handle different forms. I guess it makes some sense for a multistep form to be handled by a single controller function. Otherwise, your code would be cleaner if you breakdown each form to have its own POST handler.

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense to use a single Model class to handle multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#examples) for thorough information about various options available to use DRY coding.

Use the placeholder routing like below.

```
    $routes->post('users/(:any)', 'STD::manage_users')
```

In your controller use like below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class STD extends BaseController
{
    public function manage_users($form_name=false)
    {
        switch($form_name) 
        {
             case 'addUsers' :
                  $userModel = new UserModel();
                  $result = [
                    'name'  => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                    'gen'   => $this->request->getVar('gen'),
                    'dob'   => $this->request->getVar('dob'),
                    'email' => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                    'pwd'   => md5($this->request->getVar('pwd')),
                  ];
                  $save = $userModel->insert($result);
                  /* load success page here */
             break;
             
             case 'editUsers' :
                  /*... code to edit user ...*/
                  /* load success page here */
             break;
             
             case 'removeUsers' :
                  /*... code to remove user ...*/
                  /* load success page here */
             break;
             
             default :
                $this->response->setStatusCode(404, 'No action found with the name '.$form_name);
        }
    }
}
```